# list view component in angular which will accept any data source

Tags: angular, typescript, angular6

i wanted to create common list component like below

```
<ul>
  <li *ngFor="let item of items">{{item.text}}</li>
</ul>
```

with interface

```
export interface Items{
id:string
text:string
}
```

and in component.ts

```
@input items:any
```

now i wanted to reuse above component with any data source.

for example,

```
<app-list-view [items]="ProductList"></app-list-view>
```

& products contains.

```
this.ProductList =[PRODUCTSITEMS...]
    export interface Products{
    produceId
    productText
    }
```

may be `<app-list-view [items]="OrderList"></app-list-view>`

```
this.OrderList=[ORDERITEMS...]
export interface Orders{
    orderId
    orderText
    }
```

how can we use typescript generics or something like that here?, i do not want to use map function to create 2 more extra property on ProductList and OrderList.

what is best way to achieve above functionality.

Comment: I don't think this should be closed. It's a valid concern and a good question which shows search effort. It's useful and clear. Certainly not too broad, it's just specific enough that it helps the OP and provides a nice overview for future visitors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nice question; it's good that you want to make this component reusable for different types of lists.

Unfortunately, a generic won't help you with how your code works, it would only help you keep track of types while writing code. However, what you want to do can be implemented with an additional input.

Instead of writing `{{item.text}}` in the template and setting `.text` in stone, what if the *name* of this key is also an input? Let's call it `key`.
Then the template would look like this:

```
{{item[key]}}
```

Now we just need to make `key` an input in the class. We can give it a default value `text` so that, if you don't give the name of the key, it falls back to `item.text`.

```
@Input() key: string = 'text'
```

Now you can use your component like this:

```
<app-list-view
  [items]="productList"
  [key]="'productText'"
></app-list-view>

<app-list-view
  [items]="ordersList"
  [key]="'orderText'"
></app-list-view>
```

In both cases, the correct thing will be chosen: in the first case, it will be the same as writing `{{item.productText}}` and in the second it would be like saying `{{item.orderText}}`.

Comment: This solution is used by many famous ui frameworks like primeng . I think this should be the accepted answer.

Comment: @Lazar Ljubenović this solution work fine,** just curious can we take this approach for more complex common controls,for example, checkbox group control instead of listviewbox** ( where you need to select few product or order), please advice if you have suggestion.else i have accepted as answer. `<ul>
  <li> <input type="checkbox">
      {{item.[key]}}</li>
</ul>`

Comment: It can work with whatever. The main idea is that you pass in the `key` as yet another parameter. Just note that in your example has a syntax error, it's `item[key]`, not `item.[key]`.

Comment: Fine solution,but the problem is that it become quickly limited, when you want to use more than one field or concat the data or simply use a pipe to format the data

Comment: @xrobert35 I answered a concrete question by the OP. The first expansion would be to pass in a mapping function (like `x => x.someText`). Then it can be extended by passing in a `TemplateRef`, for example (like your answer -- which is very good but maybe over-engineered in OP's case).

Comment: Oh I don't have any problem with the solution :) it's clear and it's the simplest way to do what he want to do ;). Yes a function was a good idea but since @Var don't want additional function/properties inside the component it would be not a good answer :). 
Anyway as I said the only problem I see is the limit, since the component need to be reusable and may face different way of use ;)

Comment: @xrobert35, your solution is good also, i will try out in more complex stuff, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to be able to reuse your component with any datasource you will simply need to define a display template for your component. As a base example your component definition could look like :

For product :

```
<app-list-view [items]="ProductList">
   <ng-template #option let-data="data">{{data?.productText + ' - ' + data?.productId}}</ng-template>
</app-list-view>
```

For order :

```
<app-list-view [items]="OrderList">
   <ng-template #option let-data="data">{{data?.orderText}}</ng-template>
</app-list-view>
```

How do I use the template ?

Inside your component you will need to get the template by using the decorator **@ContentChild**. Here we select the template thanks to the **#option**

```
@ContentChild("option") optionTemplate: TemplateRef<any>;
```

Then in your component html you can now use this template :

```
<ul>
  <li *ngFor="let item of items">
     <ng-template [ngTemplateOutlet]="optionTemplate" [ngTemplateOutletContext]="{$implicit : item}"></ng-template>
  </li>
</ul>
```

---

**Bonus** : to make it more clear to use for the user you can create a (directive + component) to manage your template and make the component use look like this :

```
<app-list-view [items]="OrderList">
   <app-list-option *optionDef="let-data">{{data?.orderText}}</app-list-option>
</app-list-view>
```

The app-list-option component :

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-list-option',
  template: '<ng-content></ng-content>'
})
export class AppListOption {
  constructor() {
  }
}
```

The *optionDef  structural directive who will capture the template :

```
@Directive({
  selector: '[optionDef]',
})
export class AppListOptionDef {
  constructor(public template: TemplateRef<any>) {
  }
}
```

To finish you just need to change the selector in your component :

```
@ContentChild(AppListOptionDef ) optionDef: AppListOptionDef;
```

And use optionDef.template in the HTML :

```
<ng-template [ngTemplateOutlet]="optionDef.template" [ngTemplateOutletContext]="{$implicit : item }"></ng-template>
```

---

**For more information**

You will find here some of my code working on the way I described

Reusable "select" code : https://github.com/xrobert35/asi-ngtools/blob/master/src/components/asi-select/asi-select.component.ts

The bonus part : https://github.com/xrobert35/asi-ngtools/blob/master/src/components/common/asi-component-template.ts

Working exemple : https://ng-tools.asi.fr/views/showroom/asi-ngtools/components/asi-select